# Failed to publish MVC 4 Azure website, always get 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-404

When I'm publishing the website to staging and trying to go
https://26e33c03a5fc48e9a26089b858345c9d.cloudapp.net/ 
I'm immediately redirecting to https://26e33c03a5fc48e9a26089b858345c9d.cloudapp.net/Error/Http404/?aspxerrorpath=/Account/Login 
this issue is new and first occurred after Azure down time,
any idea why this happens?
The code work perfectly on my Machine.

i lately added the RazorEngine 3.0.8 Beta
the solution was upgrade from mvc3 to mvc4 but i published it few times and it did work.

again, this is working on my machine but not on the server, any idea why?

Comment: You need to find out why it is throwing an exception. You have something like this in your web.config. Set mode to off (or RemoteOnly if you can remote desktop into the machine running your site) <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm" mode="RemoteOnly">
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="InternalError.htm" />
    </customErrors>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V3.0.8 uses the older version of System.Web.Razor published with MVC3. Try updating to v3.1.0 which is now built around Razor 2 which came with MVC4

Answer (score 0):

The issue solved after removing the RazorEngine 3.0.8 Beta, i suggest to be careful as the beta causing real issues.